# Running tar command from php causes Cannot unlink: Read-only file system

Tags: php, laravel, backup, tar, archlinux

I am trying to implement simple backup feature of some directories (mainly directories in */etc*) which is handled by laravel. Basically I store .tar archives containing specific directory files.

This is a command used to create a backup archive of a single directory:

```
shell_exec("cd {$backupPath} && tar -cf {$dirName}.tar -P {$fullPathToDir}")
```

This is a command to restore directory from a backup archive:

```
shell_exec("cd / && sudo tar -xf {$backupPath . $dirName} --recursive-unlink --unlink-first")
```

For test reasons I let *http* user run `sudo tar`, however my initial idea was to create a bash script that will handle that, and add it to sudoers. Running command or shell script gives same errors.

The problem is if I run it through php I get errors like this:

```
Cannot unlink: Read-only file system
```

But, if i run it from command line, it works:

```
su http -s /bin/bash -c "cd / && sudo tar -xf {$backupPath . $dirName} --recursive-unlink --unlink-first"
```

Running this both on full archlinux system and archlinux docker container gives me same results. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: php run as www-data:www-data(I guess), which is not owner of file system. Needs to change permissions of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue was with systemd unit for php-fpm 7.4, where ProtectSystem was set to true, after commenting it out, everything worked as expected.

```
sed -i 's:ProtectSystem=full:#ProtectSystem=full:' /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm7.service
```